# gitlab-ci.yaml: running python in a multi line python docker image

Tags: python, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, cicd

New to gitlab and trying to do some general counting of objects from a file comprised of JSON. I know python can do the work but when running the code as a multi line statement instead of a script I am running into issues.

I am using a python image in hopes of being able to write some python in a multi line statement in one of my ci stages.

```
  stage: VerifyCode

  image: python:latest
  script:
    - ls -al
    - |
      python
      import json
      import ast
      data = open("semgrep-sast.json", "r")
```

The reason I am not using a script is because I am trying to keep the history of my changes as well as have the capability to test my changes via execution of pipeline in quick succession without added steps.

Is there a way for me to successfully execute python code from within a multi line statement?

Answer (score 0):

So this was a lapse on my end. The way to handle this is to just upload the scripts to your repository.

If you have a parent pipeline you are using, upload the scripts you want to execute to the parent pipeline repository and call it there.

That way you can just call the python scripts as you please and you will have your changes tracked.

`curl -k --header “PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GLToken}” https://gitlab.example.coml/api/v4/projects/[projectid]/repository/files/testpython.py/raw?ref=master > testpython.py`